# Парсер выводит только 27 строк вне зависимости от запроса

Tags: python, парсер

Вне зависимости от того, сколько страниц я запрашиваю пропарсить, программа выводит 27 строк результата. Как сделать так, чтобы программа выдавала количество строк пропорционально числу запрошенных для парсинга страниц?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

URL = 'https://spb.cian.ru/cat.php?deal_type=rent&engine_version=2&offer_type=flat&p=1'
HEADERS = {
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36'
}

def get_html(url, params=''):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, params=params) # r = request.get(url, headers=HEADERS, params=params) #
    return r

def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all('div', class_='_93444fe79c--card--2umme _93444fe79c--promoted--62c4a')
    rooms = []
    for item in items:
        rooms.append(
            {
                'title':item.find('div', class_='_93444fe79c--container--JdWD4').get_text(strip=True),
                'link': item.find('div', class_='_93444fe79c--container--2Kouc _93444fe79c--link--2-ANY').find('a').get('href')
            }
        )
    return rooms

def parser():
    PAGENATION = input('Введите число страниц для парсинга: ')
    PAGENATION = int(PAGENATION.strip())
    html = get_html(URL)
    if html.status_code == 200:
        roomss = []
        for page in range(1, PAGENATION+1):
            print(f'Парсим страницу {page}')
            html = get_html(URL, params={'page': page})
            roomss.extend(get_content(html.text))
        print(pd.DataFrame(get_content(html.text)))
    else:
        print('Error')

parser()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно добавить еще один знак табуляции в строке

```
print(pd.DataFrame(get_content(html.text)))
```

, чтобы получилось так:

```
def parser():
    PAGENATION = input('Введите число страниц для парсинга: ')
    PAGENATION = int(PAGENATION.strip())
    html = get_html(URL)
    if html.status_code == 200:
        roomss = []
        for page in range(1, PAGENATION+1):
            print(f'Парсим страницу {page}')
            html = get_html(URL, params={'page': page})
            roomss.extend(get_content(html.text))
            print(pd.DataFrame(get_content(html.text)))
    else:
        print('Error')
```